# I changed textContent of my span element and it seems changed on console.log but it does not change on the screen

Tags: javascript, html

This is the function where I add a new Item to my to-do list and I am adding span named "delete" to the end of my item as a button.

```
function newElement() {
count++;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("addNewItem").value;
  var t = document.createElement("Label");
  var checkB=document.createElement("input");
  checkB.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
  checkB.setAttribute("id",count);
  t.setAttribute("for",count);
  t.textContent=inputValue;
  t.appendChild(checkB);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You cannot add an empty element!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("addNewItem").value = "";
<!--adding delete button to each new item-->
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.className = "close";
  span.textContent="delete";
  console.log(span.textContent);
  li.appendChild(span);

}
```

Here I tried to change the text of span to "cancel". When I check it by console.log(span.textContent) the text looks changed as cancel but on the screen I still see the span as delete

```
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LABEL') {
     var li=e.target.parentElement;
     var label=e.target;
     label.style.textDecoration="line-through";
     var span=li.getElementsByTagName("span");
     span.textContent="cancel";
     completedTaskHolder.appendChild(li);
    }
```

[it is still still delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHuzw.jpg)

Comment: `li.getElementsByTagName("span")` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is an "array-like" object, not a span element. Use `li.querySelector("span")` to get the first span inside the list item.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you! It worked. I'm new to html and javaScript so I didn't know the difference. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're new then I'd recommend that you consult [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to learn more about the functions and API's that you're able to use. It will make development way more fun and easier. Happy coding!